# Input / Output Java

Tags: java, input, output

My program is supposed to write 100 random integers on a text file and read them. The problem is that I'm only printing 1 integer. I know I'm close. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WriteData {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //create a file instance
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("random100.txt");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //create a file
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
        //write formatted output to the file
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= 100; ++idx) {
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            output.print(randomGenerator);
            //log("Generated : " + randomInt);
            //close file 
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //create file instance
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("random100.txt");
        //create a scanner for the file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //read data from a file

        while (input.hasNext()) {

            int number = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(number + " ");
        }
        //close file
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to print `randomInt` instead of `randomGenerator`.

Answer (score 2):

output.close(); should be outside the for loop. Right now, the loop just executes once and the outputStream gets closed. Hence, you get just one number.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your output INSIDE your for, move it outside. (print randomInt not randomGenerator also)

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    //create a file instance
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("random100.txt");
    if(file.exists()){
        System.out.println("File already exists");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //create a file
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
    //write formatted output to the file
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int 0 = 1; idx < 100; ++idx){
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        output.print(randomInt);
    }
    //close file 
    output.close();
}
```